Introductory resources on rewriting logic
Hi I would like to grasp the theory behind Maude [1], [2]
Are there any recommended video lecture notes, talks or introductory notes?
I have been exposed to Functional Analysis, Topology and some Term Rewriting. But I am interested in getting into this fascinating field for formal verifications.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I would like to do my experiments in  Python or Julia or Golang (Python Software Engineering for Data Engineering is my main job). I am very open though regarding the programming language, especially if there is some code.
[1] https://maude.cs.illinois.edu/wiki/Rewriting_Logic
[2] https://maude.cs.uiuc.edu/papers/

Jose Meseguer's "Twenty Years of Rewriting Logic" (pdf) appears to be the only review paper on the (highly idiosyncratic) subject. The references therein should give you what you want.

Perhaps worth noting that rewriting logic is a (slight) generalization of equational logic which is well-studied and should have many more references.
